# How to apply ascending order within groups in bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data frame like `dat`, and I wanted to graph region-wise grouped bar plots in a way that each region is ordered from low to high. I have checked other similar questions but I couldn’t find a solution to my problem. Would appreciate if someone could advise me how to handle it.

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Region, ~var,
  "Jordan", "MENA", 42,
  "Iran", "MENA", 26,
  "Turkey", "ECA", 37,
  "Pakistan", "AP", 42,
  "Indonesia", "AP", 84,
  "Bangladesh", "AP", 24,
  "Israel", "MENA", 65
)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = Region, .fns = ~readr::parse_factor(.x, 
                                                            levels = c("AP", "ECA", "MENA"), 
                                                            ordered = TRUE))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Country), y = var, fill = Region)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `order` the `factor` within your region based on the `levels` order of your factor like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = Region, .fns = ~readr::parse_factor(.x, 
                                                            levels = c("AP", "ECA", "MENA"), 
                                                            ordered = TRUE))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Country, levels = unique(Country[order(Region, var)]), ordered = TRUE), y = var, fill = Region)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using forcats `fct_reorder()` function to sort first by var and then by Region like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = Region, .fns = ~readr::parse_factor(.x, 
                                                            levels = c("AP", "ECA", "MENA"), 
                                                            ordered = TRUE))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(Country,var) %>% 
                 fct_reorder(Region, .fun = sort), 
             y = var, fill = Region)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvvXN.png)